# How to create a share link via whatsapp from a current url

Tags: php, html, share, whatsapp

How to create a share link via whatsapp from a current url.

Hello, I have a website that has share buttons, facebook, twitter, pinterest, mail, but I want to replace two of those with whatsapp and instagram, for example I want the person who presses the share button via whatsapp to share that current url they are viewing At that moment, here I leave the code that comes by default, I would like to replace pinterest with whatsapp:

`

```
<a href="#" class="rz-close">
    <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
</a>

<div class="rz-modal-heading rz--border">
    <h4 class="rz--title"><?php esc_html_e( 'Share', 'routiz' ); ?></h4>
</div>

<div class="rz-modal-content">
    <div class="rz-modal-append">
        <div class="rz-modal-container rz-scrollbar">

            <div class="rz-signin-social rz-mb-1">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" class="rz-button rz--gg" target="_blank">
                            <span class="fab fa-facebook rz-mr-1"></span>
                            <span><?php esc_html_e( 'Share with Facebook', 'routiz' ); ?></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="rz-mt-2">
                        <a href="https://twitter.com/share?url=<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>&text=<?php echo urlencode( esc_html( get_the_title() ) ); ?>" class="rz-button rz--gg">
                            <span class="fab fa-twitter rz-mr-1"></span>
                            <span><?php esc_html_e( 'Share with Twitter', 'routiz' ); ?></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="rz-mt-2">
                        <a href="https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>&media=&description=<?php echo urlencode( esc_html( get_the_title() ) ); ?>" class="rz-button rz--gg">
                            <span class="fab fa-pinterest rz-mr-1"></span>
                            <span><?php esc_html_e( 'Share with Pinterest', 'routiz' ); ?></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="rz-mt-2">
                        <a href="mailto:?&subject=<?php echo esc_html( get_the_title() ); ?>&body=<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" class="rz-button rz--gg">
                            <span class="far fa-paper-plane rz-mr-1"></span>
                            <span><?php esc_html_e( 'Share by email', 'routiz' ); ?></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <?php Rz()->preloader(); ?>
</div>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

## WhatsApp Share Button

You can create share on WhatsApp button easily using this simple code inside the `href` of your anchor tag:

```
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=<?php echo get_permalink();; ?>
```

Here in this link you can see that inside the `text=` parameter, I'm passing the function `get_permalink()` which you have already created.

## Instagram Share Button

You can also create share on Instagram button easily using this simple code inside the `href` of your anchor tag:

```
https://www.instagram.com/sharer.php?u=<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>
```

Here in this link you can see that inside the `u=` parameter, I'm passing the same function `get_permalink()` which you have already created.

This is how you can create both of the buttons. You can use your existing code and just add these modified `href` into the anchor tags and rename them accordingly.